# Convert dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt string date to C# date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string variable that contains the following date time string. It's format is **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt**

```
string temp = "31/12/2014 12:15 AM";
```

I want to assign this date time to a C# datetime varialble.

Comment: And...? What have you tried? Did you run into any problems with the code you have? If so, please show the code.

Comment: Got a Format Exception showing : "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.TryParse`, `DateTime.ParseExact`, and `DateTime.TryParseExact` are all easy to use with lots of options depending on how strict or flexible you want to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt` (*with your `CurrentCulture`'s `DateSeparator` as well*) is standard date and time format of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) directly.

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("31/12/2014 12:15 AM");
```

If it is not, you can use custom date and time format with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
string s = "31/12/2014 12:15 AM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //
}
```

Just a note: [`/` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace current culture or supplied culture date separator*. That means if you use culture that doesn't have [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) as `/,` your parsing operation will fail *even* if your string and format match exactly.

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact is working fine for me. Thank You :)

Comment: @YeasinAbedinSiam You are quite welcome.